# Not able to use post method using rest client

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have made api in laravel and trying to access it using rest client but getting 419(unknown status). If i use get method i am able to access it through browser and rest client.

```
Route::get('/createuser',"UserController@createUser"); // works 
Route::post('/createuser',"UserController@createUser"); // error 419
```

Can anyone point me the issue?

Comment: You need to change function name in `"UserController@createUser"` to `"UserController@createPostUser"`

Comment: 419 indicates an [authentication timeout](http://getstatuscode.com/419). I feel there's more to this than you're showing

Comment: Just try to change it! See if it works! Let me if it works! :)

Comment: @HirenGohel reading the laravel docs, I don't see any problems routing different request methods for the same URL to the same method. In fact, OP could just use `Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/createuser', 'UserController@createUser')`

Comment: @HirenGohel, i changed it to createPostUser but same result. It's not working

Comment: @Phil, what is the solution?

Comment: @Hitendra I don't know but it's probably something in `UserController#createUser` that is causing the problem

Comment: Oh yes, you can't use same URL with same request!  I mean, you can't use `Route::get('/createuser', 'xx@xx')` and `Route::get('/createuser', 'yy@yy')` My mistake!

Comment: @HirenGohel, I switch between get/post. I don't use both at same time.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want to say!

Comment: There is something wrong with post. If i use method that doesn't exists in my controller then it also gives same error. So i guess if i use post it doesn't even reach to controller class and before it throws error.

Comment: I think as you are requesting `api` you should write your route in `api.php` instead `web.php`

`web.php` require `_token` the `csrf` field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `get` does not need `csrf` token, but `post` requests needs `csrf`.

And there is no problem to use the same route but different methods as you already did.

So try to except the `csrf` from the `api` or request it from the server. so you can add

```
protected $except = [
 'createuser'
];
```

to : `Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

Hope this helps

Comment: Ali, I changed it but still same error.
    protected $except = [
        'createuser/*'
    ];

Comment: I remove * from protected $except = [
 'createuser/*'
]; and it works.  Please update your answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @Hitendra, sure, I wrote it in hurry :D, thank you for the update

Comment: I just add * in  $except [] ==> protected $except = [ '*' ]; And it's worked for me.